# Setting Absolute Uri in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, routes

Is it possible to set the absoluteURI in the controller after clicking on an action link? So for example:

User clicks on a link called "GoHere". The current URL is domain.com/section/place. When the link hits the method in the controller, it recognizes that the user is currently in a section called "section", even though in the file structure section doesn't exist. The link itself actually points to domain.com/place2. Instead of returning a URL of domain.com/place2, it returns domain.com/section/place2.

The reason I ask is because for what I'm doing, the section is completely arbitrary and doesn't exist. It's just there to give the impression that the user is in another section. I know I could create extra sets of controllers, but I'm trying to get around this since for management purposes it's better if I just have one set of controllers. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: You could do this with custom routes.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm using custom routes right now and they work from the standpoint of a user typing something into the address bar. But how to make that work on a link without controllers?

Comment: What do you mean a link without controllers?

Comment: well I guess I'm misunderstanding something. I tried this: @Url.UrlRoute( new { controller = controller, action = action, section = section }) and it comes out with a url of domain.com/action?section=value Is there a way instead to do this so that it comes out as domain.com/section/action with a custom route? Can you put an answer on here with an example of the syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your gobal.asax, try setting your route to require section for the control. Maybe "{control}/section/{action}/" and whatever else you need.